# GRANT DROP ON TABLE springbootdb.* TO AdminUser

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've created an MsSQL database to serve a springboot application.

I want to grant something like the following permission to an admin user:

```
GRANT DROP ON TABLE springbootdb.* TO AdminUser
```

How can I assign this using Server Management Studio?

Comment: Are there specific things that you DO NOT want AdminUser to do? Naturally, a quick wide open solution would be to add that user to the DbOwner fixed role for that database.  You might also consider granting CONTROL to AdminUser for the entire schema involved.  If it's down to the table level, you might need to have a Sql job run to spin through the tables and dynamically generate the grant permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a specific "drop table" permission. But you can give them control on the schema using:

```
GRANT CONTROL ON SCHEMA::springbootdb TO AdminUser;
```

This allows them to drop any table in that schema, but also to do all kinds of other things you might not intend. You can take some of those things away with more granular `DENY` permissions, or with reactionary tools like DDL triggers (which can roll back operations based on the object and user).